# pandas series use gt is not pythonic way？

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get data with content greater than 3，But the type of content is string

```
a = [{"content": "1", "title": "刘德华", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
     {"content": "2", "title": "刘德华", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
     {"content": "3", "title": "刘德华", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
     {"content": "24", "title": "苹果", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
     {"content": "15", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
     {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
     ]
```

mycode

```
index=[i['content'] for i in a]

s=pd.Series(a,index)

re_index=[eval(i['content']) for i in a]
s.index=re_index
res=[]
for i,v in enumerate(s.index.__gt__(2)):
    if v:
        print(i)
        res.append(s.iloc[i])

print(res)
```

result

```
[
{'content': '3', 'title': '刘德华', 'info': '', 'time': 1582877014}, 
{'content': '24', 'title': '苹果', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}, 
{'content': '15', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
{'content': '16', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}
]
```

I think my code is too trivial
how edit my code is pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with convert `index` to numbers:

```
out = s[s.index.astype(int) > 2].tolist()
print (out)
[{'content': '3', 'title': '刘德华', 'info': '', 'time': 1582877014}, 
 {'content': '24', 'title': '苹果', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}, 
 {'content': '15', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
 {'content': '16', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[i for i in a if int(i['content']) >= 3]

[{'content': '3', 'title': '刘德华', 'info': '', 'time': 1582877014},
 {'content': '24', 'title': '苹果', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014},
 {'content': '15', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014},
 {'content': '16', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}]
```

You create a list comprehension with an if clause to get values equal to or greater than 3. note the use of int to convert to an integer. I believe you can run the program here without necessarily loading the data into pandas

Comment: i must be  loading the data into pandas